# Is the HTTP TRACE method a security vulnerability?

Tags: http

I saw many posts here on this site dishing out advice on disabling HTTP TRACE method to prevent [cross site tracing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Tracing). I sought to do the same thing. But when I read the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#traceenable), it gives the opposite advice:

> Note
>
> Despite claims to the contrary, TRACE is not a security vulnerability
>   and there is no viable reason for it to be disabled. Doing so
>   necessarily makes your server non-compliant.

Which should I follow?

Comment: Interestingly Apache's comment here is incorrect: the lack of TRACE does not make the server non-compliant. TRACE is marked a "SHOULD" in RFC-2616 and can therefore be ignored *if there is good reason* and *low practical impact*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One of the wisest security principles says that what is unused should be disabled.

So the first questions is: **Are you really going to use it? Do you need it to be enabled?**

If you are not going to use `TRACE` method then in my opinion it should be switched off. It will prevent your app not only against [XST](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Tracing), but also against undiscovered vulnerabilities related to this channel, which can be found in the future.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. What if you are using it or planning to use it?

Comment: I believe the question was about a current state of art back then. And it seems that OP was satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 22):

In order to send a `TRACE` command to a given server, you must have the right to do so, which is normally prevented by the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) (the famous "SOP"). If a piece of malicious JavaScript, intent on stealing your cookie on site `example.com`, is able to send a `TRACE` request to `example.com`, then that evil JavaScript has already won and you are in deeper trouble. Disabling `TRACE` does not solve the real problem (and that problem is client-side).

To make an outrageous analogy: there are people who murder others by stabbing them with knives. Would banning knives really solve the issue? (I'm using knives and not guns here, because it is pretty obvious that knives are very useful tools for tasks other than murdering people, e.g. I use knives daily for cooking; the same cannot be said about guns. Similarly, the HTTP `TRACE` method is a useful debugging tool.)

Comment: Most (all?) browsers prevent TRACE from working in javascript, so there's that. Doesn't prevent a java/flash app from doing it though.

Comment: @NathanC But if someone's running a Java / Flash app in their browser, they have bigger problems.

Comment: @TomLeek, Your answer asserts that `TRACE` is safe because attacks are already prevented by SOP and SOP alone. This is a halfhearted and **narrow-minded** way of analyzing security. Fact is, regardless of SOP status, malicious `TRACE` can still be sent to servers by using SSL renegotiation attacks. And what about in the future? The secure viewpoint should be that there is Every Reason to disable `TRACE`  **because its such a tasty vector** of abuse. It's like playing russian roulette with blank cartridges. Just don't.

Comment: *[cont]* Re "*Similarly, the HTTP TRACE method is a useful debugging tool*", what would be the other use cases of playing russian roulette with an actual server and are there **no safer alternative** methods? `TRACE` is actually closer in analogy  to a Katana than a typical small kitchen knife.

Answer (score 17):

> Which should I follow?

You're going to be scanning your website, what... Annually?  Quarterly?  Monthly, weekly?  And that'll show up on all those scans.  Until you tell your scanner to skip that check, or to make an exception... at which point it'll sit there until you have a third party run a scan for you, or one of your partners scans your site and puts it under your nose as *"How can you leave such a basic checklist item unaddressed?*

Conversely, you're going to be scanned for compliance to the HTTP spec... never.  You'll need to actually use TRACE... pretty much never.  The practical effect on interoperability with your clients will be... nada.

I understand and agree with @Tom-Leek's point that it's not much of a security issue.  However, I disagree in that the downside of disabling is miniscule, and the upside of disabling it is to avoid a lot of annoyance that would otherwise end up in your lap.

I'm not the only one to think that way - which is why Apache added a directive in 1.3.34 and 2.0.55 to simply shut TRACE off:

```
TraceEnable Off
```

Here's a [good page discussing it](http://www.ducea.com/2007/10/22/apache-tips-disable-the-http-trace-method/), including manual test steps.

Comment: Wow, according to Apachehaus (not sure if it's trustworthy), those 2 versions of Apache were released in 2005!

Comment: +1 for pointing out that we are often defending against auditors, CISSPs, and other earnest security folks questioning our decisions later.  This is why I often use the phrase "still vulnerable to CISSP attacks" in my security reports.

Comment: I'd like to add a very gentle word of warning about second guessing security recommendations.  Hacks can be *painfully obscure*. Just because you can't exploit a vulnerability doesn't mean a hacker can't.  To that end, keeping the auditors happy *can* be a useful security exercise even when it looks meaningless.